# How do I get the background color to go all the way to the right, in bootstrap

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have twitter bootstrap 2.04 as part of my project. I have the following HTML:

```
 <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span10 bgcolor">
      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="street">Street</label>
        <div class="controls">
          <input type="text" class="input-xxlarge" id="street">
          <span class="help-block">This field has error.</span>
        </div>
      </div>             
    </div>
  </div>
```

[image]

How do I get the background colour to go all the way to the right, i.e. at least 10 if not 12 bootstrap columns? you can see a little bit of the yellow colout I'm trying to match along the top of the pic.

Comment: Please [don't use signatures or taglines in your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).

Comment: Without code, no one is going to be able to help you. Are you using a fluid column? fixed? Post code first.

Comment: I think it is because you defined the box as `span10` so it only fills up 5/6 of the whole size. You should use `span12`

Comment: you were correct it was span12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to set the color outside of the span10 without overriding Bootstrap's span10 class, which I wouldn't recommend. You could try this (hasn't been tested):

```
<div class="row-fluid bgcolor span12">
<div class="span10">
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="street">Street</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <input type="text" class="input-xxlarge" id="street">
      <span class="help-block">This field has error.</span>
    </div>
  </div>             
</div>
```

Or just change your span10 to span12